# Cannot figure out how to get the Bootstrap dropdown button to work with my website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

www.wishywell.net

I read the Bootstrap guide and it should be as easy as adding these lines of code to have a button with a dropdown menu

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">Features <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="blog.html" tabindex="-1">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="single.html" tabindex="-1">Blog Single</a></li>
        <li><a href="dividers.html" tabindex="-1">Dividers</a></li>
    </ul></li>
```

At the top, the word Feature shows up but there's dropdown, is something else on my website causing it to fail?

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly make use of Bootstrap's Javascript components, you'll want to include the bootstrap.js(or bootstrap.min.js) file as a resource on your site's page.

You can find these files within the zipball provided by bootstrap:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you need to call bootstrap javascript components.

You also need to change the http://www.wishywell.net/js/backtotop.js file like

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    application.init ();


(function () {
        a('<i id="back-to-top" class="icon-chevron-up"></i>').appendTo(a("body"));
        a(window).scroll(function () {
            if (a(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
                a("#back-to-top").fadeIn()
            } else {
                a("#back-to-top").fadeOut()
            }
        });
        a("#back-to-top").click(function () {
            a("body,html").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 600)
        })
    })();

});
```

and call it *after* you have called the jquery file like

```
    <!-- Start: Java Script -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/flexslider/2.0/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/backtotop.js"></script>
```